# Read from TlsStream<TcpStream> using `tokio-rustls` in Rust

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I am using `rustls`, and want to read `TlsStream` to a buffer likewise we read `TcpStream`. Here is what I am doing:

```
let acceptor = TlsAcceptor::from(Arc::new(config));

let fut = async {

    let mut listener = TcpListener::bind(&addr).await?;

    loop {

        let (stream, peer_addr) = listener.accept().await?;
        let acceptor = acceptor.clone();

        let fut = async move {

            let mut stream = acceptor.accept(stream).await?;

            //// CURRENTLY THIS .read() is throwing error in compiler
            println!("Stream: {:?}", stream.read(&mut [0; 1024]));

            Ok(()) as io::Result<()>
        };

        handle.spawn(fut.unwrap_or_else(|err| eprintln!("{:?}", err)));
    }
};
```

It throws error

```
'error[E0599]: no method named `read` found for struct `tokio_rustls::server::TlsStream<tokio::net::tcp::stream::TcpStream>` in the current scope'
```

I am looking to read from `TlsStream` generated using `tokio-rustls` to buffer.

Comment: What is the full error message? That likely includes some hints about what to do to solve the problem.

Comment: Amazing, thanks @Frxstream. That was that silly on my side. I havent read the complete error message. It said `the following trait is implemented but not in scope; perhaps add a use for it: use tokio::io::util::async_read_ext::AsyncReadExt;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your error message describes, there's a trait [`AsyncReadExt`](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.2/tokio/io/trait.AsyncReadExt.html) that's implemented for the type, but not imported into scope. To be able to use the [`read`](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.2/tokio/io/trait.AsyncReadExt.html?search=#method.read) method of that trait, you need to import the trait; for this trait, this is typically done by importing the [tokio prelude](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.2/tokio/prelude/index.html):

```rust
use tokio::prelude::*;

// or you can explicitly import just AsyncReadExt, but I'd recommend the above
use tokio::io::AsyncReadExt;
```

In addition, you need to specifically `await` the result from `read()`, since it returns a future. You also need to use a buffer in a separate variable, since that's where the read data is stored.

```rust
let mut buffer = [0; 1024];
let byte_count = stream.read(&mut buffer).await;
//                                       ^^^^^^
println!("Stream: {:?}", &buffer[0..byte_count]);
```

Comment: I implemented the use statement as you said and update this `let inward_stream = stream.read(&mut [0; 1024]).await; println!("Stream: {:?}", inward_stream.unwrap());` But this gives me `Stream: 581` as ouput in console insted of the inward stream data like `HTTP ....`

Comment: @kanudo `.read()` returns the number of bytes read, the actual data is stored in the buffer that you pass in (which you need to store in a variable a guess, a temporary array is pretty useless in this case).

Comment: What would you suggest instead of temp array?

Comment: @kanudo The simplest is to just use a variable to store the array, as I've updated my answer to do.

Comment: I dit it same way `let mut buffer = [0; 1024];` thats great it worked. Many thanks :)